# Phonegap GetJson Strange Output - REST

Tags: json, rest, debugging, cordova, getjson

I am having this situation: ( public api a test website of mine )

```
  $.getJSON("http://ee-tutz.com/entry_api/rest/read_entry/json?auth[username]=test&auth[password]=guest&data[entry_id]=80",function(data){
        alert(data); // here i get [obj Obj]
       var tweetlistHTML = "";
        for(var i = 0; i< data.results.length;i++){
            tweetlistHTML +='<li>'+data.results[i].title+ '</li>'
        }
        var tweetList = $("#tweetlist");
        tweetList.html(tweetlistHTML);
    });
```

Is anything worng with the code ?
I want to output some data of out the resulting from the URL ( for example Title )
But it Doesen't Output the titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to output the object details using `JSON.stringify()` method.
This will let you know the returned `object properties` and `values`.
**e.g:** alert the first object details.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.results[0]));
```

OR the entire objects in the array.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.results));
```

Also did you try to check the results form the desktop browser whether the URL is returning JSON response.
**EDIT1:**
I just checked the response of the URL
You need to change the data variable syntax.

```
data.data[i].title
```

instead of

```
data.results[i].title
```

**EDIT2:**
Oops. I forgot to change my alert code.
The alert should be.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.data[0]));
```

or you could alert the whole data.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**EDIT3:**
Your JSON data returned by the URL
http://ee-tutz.com/entry_api/rest/read_entry/json?auth[username]=test&auth[password]=guest&data[entry_id]=80
**JSON data:**

```
{"message":"Successfully readed","code":200,"code_http":200,"data":[{"entry_id":"80","site_id":"1","channel_id":"1","author_id":"1","forum_topic_id":null,"ip_address":"86.120.164.135","title":"POP ON OP: an Interactive Real-Time Animation Object-Book","url_title":"pop-on-op-an-interactive-real-time-animation-object-book","status":"open","versioning_enabled":"y","view_count_one":"0","view_count_two":"0","view_count_three":"0","view_count_four":"0","allow_comments":"y","sticky":"n","entry_date":"1405812194","year":"2014","month":"07","day":"20","expiration_date":"0","comment_expiration_date":"0","edit_date":"20140719233024","recent_comment_date":"0","comment_total":"0","main_content":"POP ON OP is an interactive real-time animation object-book in which you can experience movement directly on paper with a special film.","propietati":"74%$23,959 Funded &nbsp; ","testfisier":false,"poza":"<img alt=\"Photo little\" class=\"fit\" height=\"150\" src=\"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/ksr\/projects\/1055334\/photo-little.jpg?1404412397\" width=\"200\" \/>","descriere":" POP ON OP is an interactive real-time animation object-book in which you can experience movement directly on paper with a special film. ","autor":"  by PARRATORO  ","categories":[]}],"id":"80"}
```

Comment: Well, Did the changes but yet undefined on the alert, and also replaced the code yet, the code didn't show on the page. :( and on thealert(JSON.stringify(data.results[0])); <- it didn't show any alert

Comment: In the code you have shown you get an alert `\\here i get [obj Obj]`. Are you getting an alert or not?

Comment: Yes I do, I made it through and coded the solution in the last minutes, now i have another problem, the Json data that comes is like {"uselessstuff":"value","dataiwant":[{obj},{obj}]} <- how can i pass over every object in this multidimensional object?

Comment: You need to use `for(var i = 0; i< data.dataiwant.length;i++){
            data.dataiwant[i].fieldIWant;}`

Comment: You are welcome. please **accept** the **answer** if it has solved your issue. Also next time provide as much information as you can so others can find it easy to understand your problem.